# Visual Studio 2013 - Git - Fetch remote branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am starting to use Visual Studio 2013 with the built-in Git Team Explorer tools using Visual Studio Online.  I am very familiar with how to do this via the Git Shell but cannot seem to figure out how to do this via the VS 2013 interface.

I am trying to pull a remote branch locally and am unable to do so.  Via command line, I would do:

```
git fetch -a
git checkout <branchName>
```

I understand the workflow is to create a local branch that tracks the remote branch; however, my remote branch list in the dropdown is not complete.  How do I perform this action which mimics `git fetch -a`?

Below is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I would expect to see `origin/dev` there, also.  Did you do a fetch from the sync page?

Comment: @EdwardThomson You are correct, the fetch solved the problem.  Just seemed disjoint given the workflow.  The Unsynced Commits page seemed to function under the scope of a branch.  I wasn't expecting to find Fetch there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To perform the equivalent of `git fetch` from the Git Team Explorer tools with Visual Studio 2013, you have to:

1. Go to the ***Unsynced Commits*** tab
2. Switch to a branch that has remote tracking (I always use master)
3. Click ***Fetch*** under the ***Incoming Commits*** section

Now, your remote branch list will be up to date and you can create a new branch that tracks the `origin/dev` branch

[image]