# Unable to get all branches from Git in Team services

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am using team services git as repository.
I have 3 branches in Git repository.

But when I clone the repository in Visual studio 2015, I am able to clone only the `master` branch of the repository.

Is there a way so that I can clone all the branches of the repository using visual studio.
I have attached the branch structure and the branch in the VS I am able to see only the `master` branch.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning a repo only creates and checkout *one* branch (the default one, generally master, linked to the remote tracking branch origin/master)

You should be able to fetch and see the other branches as origin/xxx (see "[Visual Studio 2013 - Git - Fetch remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32639105/6309)")

See also "[Connecting to a remote Git branch from Visual Studio](http://www.almguide.com/2014/12/connecting-to-a-remote-git-branch-from-visual-studio/)" from [Esteban Garcia](http://www.almguide.com/about/).

> before you can see the branches locally, you need to create a local tracking branch for the remote branch.  You could do this with command-line:

```
git branch dev –track origin/dev
```

> You can also do this right from Visual Studio.
>
> First, click on “New Branch”
>   Then select the remote branch from the drop-down list, this will auto-populate the branch local name.

[image: http://www.almguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/image_thumb4.png]